# How to use change event and mapActions

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to rewrite the following code using `mapActions`.
What I want to do is to send the **keywords** entered in the input element to the store.

**before**

```
<template>
  <input @input="change" />
</template>

<script>

export default {
  methods: {
    change(e) {
        const keyword = e.target.value;
        this.$store.dispatch("search/doSearch", keyword);
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

**after**

```
<template>
  <input @input="change" />
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  methods: {
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　//　I want to use mapActions
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it

```html
<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('search', ['doSearch']),
    
    change(e) {
      this.doSearch(e.target.value)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It can also be done as `...mapActions({ searchFromApi: 'search/doSearch' })` if you want to rename the function in the template for some reasons